# How to truncate hyperlink text but not hyperlink itself in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, truncate

Happily using `Rinku` gem to autolink my text. This is helpful when someone pastes in a URL in a comment - `Rinku` will autolink that URL.

However, really long URLs are messing with the page layout. It would be helpful for every hyperlink encountered:

- Shorten the hyperlink text
- Keep the underlying hyperlink

e.g. `http://www.yahoo.com` may be displayed as `http://www.ya...` but in the underlying HTML, the hyperlink is `http://www.yahoo.com`. Twitter does this with tweets.

Have been searching high and low for any existing gems or prior experience on this. Haven't come up with anything so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/tanoku/rinku/blob/master/README.markdown) Rinku supports customization of the link text:

```
auto_link(text) do |url|
    url.truncate :length => 15
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I missed it in all the late-night reading (there's probably a lesson in that :) Now ... I could only get it to work like this: `url.truncate(15)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Rinku, but you could easily do this from within the view:

```
<% trunk_url = truncate(url, :length => 15) %><%= link_to(trunk_url, url) %>
```

Basically, truncate the url itself into a string (trunk_url), then use that as the text for the link_to.  In my case, the url was a field (tm.website).  Works perfectly.